# Why can't I rename column names and why are column names in my pandas DataFrame in parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, rename

I am trying to rename all my columns and then drop several columns. However, every time I try to rename a column, the name is in parentheses and won't drop when selected. How can I remedy this? Reset header?

[What the column names look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPc2X.png)

Comment: Can you share sample data and code which you already tried? It would be easier for us if the data is not in an image.

Comment: Please don't post images, instead paste everything as text. Also, please share sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, check out this example

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
df = pandas.DataFrame({"(drop3,)": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],"(drop4,)": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],"(drop5,)": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # renaming the columns
df = df.drop('a',1) # dropping the column named 'a' for example 
df
```